# Flash fall back controls not being styled correctly with mediaelement.js

Tags: flash, mediaelement.js

I'm running this on my local IIS server and I'm having an issue where when using the flash fallback for mediaelement.js - the timeline slider doesn't appear, the background styles don't show up - the captions have no background, the closed caption menu is not styled and impossible to select an option... - I think these are all steming from the same problem.

All of this works when running as HTML 5 though.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here's a link to an image to show the issue I'm having:
[mediaelement.js flash bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgeLk.jpg)